# calc() as SVG coordinate does not re-render when parent width changes

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

### The Issue

In the following HTML code, I'm using the css `calc()` function to make an SVG line a percentage of the width of the parent container, minus a constant 20px:

```html
<button onclick="myOnClick()">Click me</button>
<div id="my-div">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <line
          x1="0px"
          x2="calc(100% - 20px)"
          y1="30px"
          y2="50px"
          stroke="#0000FF"
          strokeWidth="10px"
      />
  </svg>
</div>
```

When the button is clicked, the width of the parent container is changed.

```js
function myOnClick() {
  document.getElementById("my-div").style.width = "400px";
}
```

The expected behavior is that the line should change its ending coordinate to take into account the new width of the container. However, the line does not change width.

If you go into the element inspector and then change the `x2` of the line to another value, then back to `calc(100% - 20px)`, the line DOES update and takes on the new width of the container. This leads me to believe this is a rendering bug in Chrome.

### Other Cases

Curiously, when I change one of the y coordinates to a percentage, rather than a pixel value, it works as expected:

```html
<button onclick="myOnClick()">Click me</button>
<div id="my-div">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <line
          x1="0px"
          x2="calc(100% - 20px)"
          y1="30px"
          y2="100%"         <-- LINE CHANGED
          stroke="#0000FF"
          strokeWidth="10px"
      />
  </svg>
</div>
```

```js
function myOnClick() {
  document.getElementById("my-div").style.width = "400px";
}
```

```css
#my-div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myOnClick()">Click me</button>
<div id="my-div">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <line
          x1="0px"
          x2="calc(100% - 20px)"
          y1="30px"
          y2="100%"
          stroke="#0000FF"
          strokeWidth="10px"
      />
    <line
          x1="0px"
          x2="calc(100% - 20px)"
          y1="30px"
          y2="50px"
          stroke="#0000FF"
          strokeWidth="10px"
      />
  </svg>
</div>
```

### Question

Is this expected behavior, or is this a bug in Chrome that should be reported?

This question only pertains to Chrome, as Firefox and Safari do not seem to support the `calc()` function for SVG components.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why chrome actually does support calc in SVG. That seems... unholy. I wouldn't rely on this technique.

Comment: line elements x1, x2, y1, y2 are not CSS properties so I don't think using calc here is valid at all. Firefox (and likely Safari too) do support calc for CSS properties.

Comment: @somethinghere spec quote: "A future specification may convert the ‘x1’, ‘y1’, ‘x2’, and ‘y2’ attributes to geometric properties." That would be a loophole for Chrome to justify deviating from the spec. Just the same, I think it warrants a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `calc()` doesn't work for svg attributes in Firefox or Safari, you could get a similar layout
by applying **padding** to the parent `<svg>`

```js
function myOnClick() {
  document.getElementById("my-div").style.width = "400px";
}
```

```css
#my-div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myOnClick()">Click me</button>
<div id="my-div">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    
    <line
          x1="0px"
          x2="100%"
          y1="30px"
          y2="100%"
          stroke="#0000FF"
          strokeWidth="10px"
      />
    <line
          x1="0px"
          x2="100%"
          y1="30px"
          y2="50px"
          stroke="#0000FF"
          strokeWidth="10px"
      />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

calc() is a CSS function and the [x2 attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line#attributes) is not a presentation attribute (can not be used in CSS) and can only take a length, number or percentage.

What if the width of the SVG was `100% - 20px` like in this example:

```js
function myOnClick() {
  document.getElementById("my-div").style.width = "400px";
}
```

```css
#my-div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

svg {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myOnClick()">Click me</button>
<div id="my-div">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <line x1="0" y1="30"
          x2="100%" y2="50"
          stroke="#0000FF"
          stroke-width="10" />
  </svg>
</div>
```